# How to make a return in a loop only when everything is looped through

Tags: android, loops, flutter, dart

I would like to create a loop where everything is run through once and is returned. But my problem is that it is not looped correctly and immediately sets the return. How can I solve this?

```
  String _loadHtml2(String) {
    for (int i = 0; i < _list[0].length; i++) {
      return r'''
          ''' +
          _list[0][i] +
          '''
          </body>
          </html>
          ''';
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

couldn't you make each loop add to a variable, and then return the variable outside of the for loop?

```
 String _loadHtml2(String) {
    var foo = ''
    for (int i = 0; i < _list[0].length; i++) {
      foo += r'''
          ''' +
          _list[0][i] +
          '''
          </body>
          </html>
          ''';
    }
    return foo
  }
```

something like that? i'm not sure about the exact syntax, but that's how i would do it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what are you trying to achieve exactly, but you can build a string through the loop. At first you declare a String variable, which is empty.
Then in the loop you start adding all the things you want to the string. Once the loop is finished you can still add something, but then those things are added only one time. And then you can return the String that you built.

```
String _loadHtml2(String) {
        var answer = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < _list[0].length; i++) {
          answer += _list[0][i] + " Something more";
        }
        answer += "</body>\n</html>";
        return answer;
      }
```

Lets imagine that the list contains strings ["foo","bar"]. Then after running that code your code will return:

```
foo Something morebar Something more</body>
</html>
```

Since it takes \n as a linebreak.